# Is it possible to shrink the size of an HP Smart Array logical drive?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I know extension is quite possible using the `hpacucli` utility, but is there an easy way to reduce the size of an existing logical drive (not array)?

The controller is a P410i in a ProLiant DL360 G6 server. I'd like to reduce logicaldrive 1 from 72GB to 40GB.

```
=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Serial Number: 5001438006FD9A50
   Cache Serial Number: PAAVP9VYFB8Y
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Chassis Slot: 
   Hardware Revision: Rev C
   Firmware Version: 3.66
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 3 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60 min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 15 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Accelerator Ratio: 25% Read / 75% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Enabled
   Total Cache Size: 512 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Batteries
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 412476 MB
      Status: OK

         Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 72.0 GB
         Fault Tolerance: RAID 1+0
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 18504
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         Array Accelerator: Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C132E4BBDFAA6DAD13DA3
         Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d0
         Mount Points: /boot 196 MB, / 12.0 GB, /usr 8.0 GB, /var 4.0 GB, /tmp 2.0 GB
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Logical Drive Label: AE438D6A5001438006FD9A50BE0A
         Mirror Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250
      Device Number: 250
      Firmware Version: RevC
      WWID: 5001438006FD9A5F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model:  SRC 8x6G
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Page 41 of the SA Configuration Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02289065/c02289065.pdf) says no. You can only create, delete, extend, and migrate (plus some information and recovery commands).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to boot from [Parted Magic](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=partedmagic) and see if you can resize down? I have found it to be very helpful.

If it is not the boot drive, back up the data and make a new partition.

Comment: erm...but that would be the partition, not the logical drive...

Comment: SA Logical Drives show up as whole hard drives in partition managers. Perhaps there would be some educational material in *The Manual™* I posted in my answer.