# Shrink an HP Smart Array on a P400

Tags: hp, sas, hard-drive

I just started consulting for a new client and one of 6 hard drives in their server's SAS array failed. Going over the options of replacing the drive, they didn't like the thought of spending about ~$350 for a drive replacement at this time. Instead, they inquired if it would be possible to just pull the failed drive and get by since there is plenty of excess storage space.

I tried running the command:
ctrl slot=1 array a remove drives=2I:1:5

to remove the failed physical drive but I was given this error:
This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the "show" command on devices to show additional details about the configuration.

I've looked through documentation and it seems to be possible, I'm just not sure I have the syntax of the command correct and using the 'show' command doesn't reveal anything that pops out at me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't shrink those arrays, only grown them, I don't know why you think it may be possible.

[HERE](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12400_div/12400_div.HTML)'s the quickspecs showing what can be done.

Comment: Thanks. One of the many PDFs I was looking at last night from HP seemed to say it was supported. The command given after the section didn't work - now I know why.

Comment: There is some logic that if you can grow why can't you shrink but there are some dull complexities that always get in the way on most machines sorry.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Please see: [Is it possible to shrink the size of an HP Smart Array logical drive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243213/is-it-possible-to-shrink-the-size-of-an-hp-smart-array-logical-drive)